# Java 8 find first instance of value in multidimensional array of objects

Tags: java, arrays, java-8, java-stream

Trying to understand how to use some java 8 features and was playing around with multidimensional array of objects, if I wanted to find the first instance of a value in a multidimensional array of objects.

```
Objects[][] someArray= .....


Arrays.stream(someArray)
                .map(someArrayFirst -> Arrays.stream(someArrayFirst))
                .map(unsure what to do here)
                .filter(a -> a.equals("some value"))
                .findFirst();
```

edit, thanks for the input. Just to help others out here is what I have now.

```
 Arrays.stream(someArray)
                .flatMap(someArrayFirst -> Arrays.stream(someArrayFirst))
                .filter(MyCustomClass.class::isInstance)
                .map(MyCustomClass.class::cast)
                .filter(v -> v.value().equalsIgnoreCase("SomeString"))
                .findFirst();
```

Comment: Use `flatMap` instead of `map` (and remove the second `map`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are on the right track. You need to turn the two dimensions into a single stream and then take the first element that satisfies your condition:

```
String[][] array;
Optional<String> result = Arrays.stream(array)
    .flatMap(Arrays::stream)
    .filter("some value"::equals).findFirst();
```

The first `stream` produces a `Stream<String[]>`. The flat map turns each of the array elements into a `Stream<String>`. Then it's just filtering for the value you want and getting the first element that satisfies your condition.

Comment: What if I want to get the index of that value.

Comment: @ShirshSinha the solution is quite different if you want the index rather than the value. In that case you use `IntStream`. But it warrants a separate question and answer rather than me shoehorning the solution into this answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
static String[][] arr = new String[][]{{"x","y"},{"z","v"},{"b","z"}};
static String searchStr = "x";
static String searchObj = null;

public static void main(String... args) {

    Arrays.stream(arr)
    .forEach((subarr)->{
        Optional<String> opt = Arrays.stream(subarr)
                .filter((obj)->obj.equals(searchStr))
                .findFirst();
        if (opt.isPresent())
            searchObj = opt.get();
    });
    System.out.println(searchObj);
}
```

or

```
static public String mapFlatMethod(String[][] arr, String searchStr) {
    return Arrays.stream(arr).flatMap(row -> Stream.of(row))
            .filter((obj)->obj.equals(searchStr))
            .findFirst().get();

}
```

Comment: Comment on your first solution: generally it's bad practice to have lambda expressions with side effects (such as assigning a value to a variable). There are lots of good explanations of why this is bad practice on SO and elsewhere.

Comment: Comment on your second solution: the `get` will throw an exception if no elements pass the filter predicate. That's probably not what you want. Better use `orElse(null)` or (preferably) return an `Optional`.